# Бессмертный сервис для Push

Tags: android, firebase, push

Проблема следующая, при закрытом(не свернутом) приложении Push сообщения не приходят. Использую FireBase. Пока приложение открыто или в фоне, все работает.

```
public class MessagingFirebase extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "message";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();

            android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //иконка уведомления
                    .setAutoCancel(true) //уведомление закроется по клику на него
                    .setTicker(remoteMessage.getData().get("message")) //текст, который отобразится вверху статус-бара при создании уведомления
                    .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message")) // Основной текст уведомления
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT))
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) //отображаемое время уведомления
                    .setContentTitle("AppName") //заголовок уведомления
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL); // звук, вибро и диодный индикатор выставляются по умолчанию

            Notification notification = nb.getNotification(); //генерируем уведомление
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(100, notification); // отображаем его пользователю.

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
}



public class getTokenFirebase extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.e("token", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    //startForeground(100000,viewNotification());
}
```

}

### AndroidManifest

```
<service
        android:name=".Service.getTokenFirebase">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".Service.MessagingFirebase">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: У меня все работает. Делал по докам все приходит. Под закрыто вы имеете в виду когда из многозадачности смахнули?
Проверьте еще раз все ли вы сделали по докам или какой то пункт упустили

Comment: Да, получается свапаю из списка запущенных приложений. И все после это не работает.

Comment: покажите код, что и как вы делаете, иначе, ответить на ваш вопрос - невозможно.

Comment: @mit добавил код.

Comment: title в data обязательно указывайте

Comment: @Николай, не в этом было дело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, Ваша проблема состоит в формате отправляемого пуш сообщения. Внимательно ознакомьтесь с этой ссылкой: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages.
Попробуйте в JSON сообщения положить информацию под ключ `data` и обрабатывать ее сервисом, полностью исключив ключ `notification`.
**UPDATE**: Если проверяете на китайском телефоне (xiaomi, meizu), есть вероятность того, что при выгрузке приложения из памяти выгружается и сервис сообщений. У Xiaomi прошивки такая особенность точно есть.

Comment: "{"registration_ids":["this-key"],"data":{"message":"Text"},"content_available":true,"priority":"normal"}" Вот такой я отправляю.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев Попробуйте проверить, выгружается ли сервис. Можно попробовать поставить пример от Firebase cloud messaging, выгрузить и проверить, будет ли приходить пуш.

Comment: При запущенном приложении, после прихода push срабатывает onDestroy у FirebaseMessagingService