# нету тела push notification когда приложение не на фоне

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android, google-cloud-messages, messaging

Всем привет, не работают уведомления когда приложение свернуто, хотя когда оно на переднем плане все хорошо

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Class<?> c = null;
        int activeWindow = Integer.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("active_window"));
        int activeItemId = Integer.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("active_item_id"));

        c = PushWindowConstants.getClassForId(activeWindow);


        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<NotificationMessage> notificationMessages = gson.fromJson(remoteMessage.getData().get("messages"),
                new TypeToken<ArrayList<NotificationMessage>>() {
                }.getType());
        for (NotificationMessage message : notificationMessages) {
            if (message.getLanguage().equals("RU")) {
                showNotification(message.getBody(), activeItemId, c);
                break;
            }
        }

        ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this, ++App.notificationCounter);
    }
}
```

вот как строится само уведомление

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = 
    getString(R.string.notification_channel_id_for_messages);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)

    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_message)

    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(message))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + 
    getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification));

    builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

notificationManager.notify(App.notificationID++, builder.build());
```

Данные идут не через notification а через data и все равно не работает...

Comment: У вас есть телефон на чистом андройде?

Comment: нет, тестирую на 4.4 и на 6.0 андроиде

Comment: я имел ввиду, что по верх андройда никаких оболочек не установлено. Просто, у меня уже было такое. на телефоне HTC 4.4.2 все работало хорошо, а на ASUS 5.0 не работало когда сворачивал приложение. Оказалось, что на ASUS были установлены доп.софт по "безопасности", которое запрещало использовать фоновые процессы для моего приложения.

Comment: нет, по верх ничего не установлено

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653104/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-push) Вот мой вопрос был на stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

В данных нотификации установите **content-available = 1**

Comment: (почитал что это, но у меня приложение для андроида)